# Storing user searches and notify them when something is available MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, search

Storing user searches and notify them when something is available php-
I've created a local exchange trading server where users trade particular skills they acquire within a community for LETS credits. I would like to be able to save user searches if they are not available and to prompt them if that particular skill becomes available;
User case; User_1 looks for a Php developer for a web application however one is not available so far. When one does become available lets say User_2, I would like user one notified. Conceptionally can someone help me how to get this best resolved.

Answer (score 0):

> Conceptionally can someone help me how to get this best resolved.

Let's say that all skills and users are assigned an id.

**Users**

```
USER ID | USER NAME
------------------
1       | User1
2       | User2
```

**Skills**

```
SKILL ID | SKILL NAME
------------------
1       | Web Developer
```

When User 1 searches for a web developer, if no one is free, their search would be added to a table of waiting users.

**WAITING**

```
USER ID | SKILL ID
------------------
1       | 1
```

When `User2`, a web developer, is freed, the computer would search through `WAITING` for anyone that wants a web developer and find `User1`. The computer would then alert `User1` that `User2` is free and delete the row in `WAITING`, as it is no longer needed.